# Oracle Comma Separated Value (ID) in a Column. How to get Description for each Value in a Comma Separated string.

Tags: oracle, select, join, split, case

Sorry for the Confusing title.I myself did not understand it when i read it second time.

So here is the details description.

I have a table say "Awards" which have following Column:
Name,
Amount,
Employee

and Another table "Employee" which have following column:
Emp_Id,
Emp_Name

and in employee column of "Awards" table i have value "01,20" which are actually the Employee ID referenced to "Employee" table.

So is there any way i can get Employee Name in select "Awards" query?

Comment: Yes, change your schema, the Awards table should be reworked with one line per award/employee relationship. (That will probably mean one more table if you want to normalize properly.)

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the suggestion and yes that is the correct way to go, but in my case if i do change the table design i'll have to change the code(insert,update) on application pages and i don't want to jump into the code for now.

Comment: The more you wait to do that change, the harder it will get.

Comment: Yes and i'll start to change it soon.But for now i really needed this for one report.

Comment: Let me guess, a front-end app developer created the db schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the Database (added one more table). and already started changing the CODE, as for the said report i have used following

```
WITH t AS
   (
      Select emp_name from  employee where  emp_id in (
        select regexp_substr(Employee ,'[^,]+', 1, level) from awards 
        connect by regexp_substr((select Employee from awards ), '[^,]+', 1, level) is
        not null)
   )
SELECT  LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(emp_name, ','),',') emp_name
FROM ( SELECT emp_name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY emp_name) FILA
       FROM t )
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH FILA = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR FILA = FILA - 1
```

Which is temporary and i understand very less of it.

Thanks for you help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Given below is the query to get comma seperated employee ids in form of rows which I put in subquery to get their name. Please edit as per your ewquirements.

```
 Select Ename from  employee where employee_id in (
 SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS
  from awards t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(Employee,':','</e><e>')||  
  '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have tried the query but has not been able to add where clause to sub-query(select trim columns...).  
I keep getting SQL Command Not Ended Properly Error.

And also I think if Employee column in Award has value '6,26' then i will get two different rows.Instead i want 'Prashant,Anil' in one column 
Only if that's possible.

Thanks again.

Comment: 1)There was one extra bracket which would have been giving you problem 2) You get different names in rows please concat them again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select a.*, e.EmpName
from Awards a join
     Employees e
     on ','||a.employee||',' like '%,'||e.emp_id||',%';
```

This will return the employee names on separate lines.  If you want them in a list, then you would need to concatenate them together (and the best function for doing that depends on your version of Oracle).

By the way, this is a very bad data structure,  You should have an association table AwardEmployee that has one row for each row and each employee.